# Using Return round(function,1) giving syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

[image]

Why python give **Sytanx error ''RETURN OUTSIDE FUNCTION''** 
*Error line 35 :>>>> return round(temp_c,1)* ? I'm beginner programmer and i want to store my sensor data mysql . As you see my return round(temp_c,1) in my function and if statement.
 Here is my full code

import os
    import time
    import datetime
    import glob
    import mysql.connector
    from mysql.connector import errorcode
    from time import strftime

```
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

temp_sensor = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000008a43c0e/w1_slave'


#Connect MySQL
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='invoker',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='temp-at-interrupt')
cnx.close()

#
#Get Temperature Values.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def tempRead():
    t = open(temp_sensor, 'r')
    lines = t.readlines()
    t.close()

temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
if temp_output != -1:
    temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
    temp_c = float(temp_string)/1000.0
    return round(temp_c,1)


#Insert new data
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
while True:
    print(temp)
    datatimeWrite = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d ") + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    print (datetimeWrite)
    sql = ("""INSERT INTO tempLog (datetime,temperature) VALUES (%s,%s)""",(datetimeWrite,temp))
try:
    print ("Writing to database...")
# Execute the SQL command
    cur.execute(*sql)
# Commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()
    print ("Write Complete")

except:
# Rollback in case there is any error
    db.rollback()
    print ("Failed writing to database")

cur.close()
db.close()
break
```

Comment: Your indentation is b0rked.

Comment: Hello vaultah, firstly my bad, temp_output and if statement inside the tempRead() Function. I want to collect more then one values, so i need return right ?

Comment: @NjordNyström You can return more than one value from a function, as a [Tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) or a [List](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists). Please ask follow up questions in a new question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `return` not inside a function, which is illegal Python (and most programming languages) syntax.

```
if temp_output != -1:
    temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
    temp_c = float(temp_string)/1000.0
    return round(temp_c,1)  # <---- problematic return statement outside a function
```

---

I believe that this `if` block is part of `tempRead()` function, so a fix is to delete the empty line before the `if` block, and ident all the code in the `if` block by 4 spaces:

```
def tempRead():
    t = open(temp_sensor, 'r')
    lines = t.readlines()
    t.close()
    temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
    if temp_output != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string)/1000.0
        return round(temp_c,1)
```

Comment: Hi galfisher , you helped me to solve my problem ! Thanks . Probably i do same mistake while/break part.

Comment: Best of luck @NjordNyström and feel free to ask followup questions in the future.